# Send form data via AJAX to multiple PHP files

Tags: ajax

So, i have no clue if what i want to do is even possible, but i tried and failed ;P

```js
        <script>
            $("#submitdata").submit(function()
            {
                var datefrom=document.getElementById( "datefrom" );
                var dateto=document.getElementById( "dateto" );
                var dropdown=document.getElementById( "dropdown" ).value;

                alert (dropdown);

                if (dropdown === "0") {
                    alert ("Please choose first!");
                } else if (dropdown === "1") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'showData.php',
                        data: {
                            datefrom: datefrom,
                            dateto: dateto,
                            choice: dropdown
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            $('#inner').load('#inner');
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                } else if (dropdown === "2") {
                } else if (dropdown === "3") {
                } else if (dropdown === "4") {
                }

            });
        </script>
```

```html
<form method="post" id="submitdata" name="submitdata">
                                <div class="row uniform">
                                    <div class="12u 12u$">
                                        <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="datefrom" value="" placeholder="From" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u 12u$">
                                        <input type="text" name="dateto" id="dateto" value="" placeholder="To" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        <div class="select-wrapper">
                                            <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                                                <option value="0">- Choose -</option>
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="special" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

I want to send the data to different files, depending on what the user chooses in the form dropdown (if that is possible).
I get the alerts and everything is fine but it just jumps into the other "elseif's" even tho the value of dropdown is "0".

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: There's nothing *in* those `else if` blocks, so how have you confirmed that it's doing this?  This code doesn't really demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I just didnt fill the other blocks yet. The data get transfered even tho dropdown is 0. Or gets the data send independently and it doesnt matter that dropdown !== 1?

Comment: Something else is wrong, or you have an incorrect assumption somewhere.  The JavaScript implementation of `if` and `else if` blocks does, in fact, work.  This is trivial to test: https://jsfiddle.net/uz718gty/  You're going to need to do some more debugging to find out what's actually happening here.  "The data gets transferred" is pretty broad and vague.  Is the AJAX request being made?  Or is the form posting normally?  Is this `submit` handler perhaps being invoked twice?  Is something else happening?  Drop your assumptions and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution eventually:

```js
                if(!datumvon.value){
                    alert("Watch out");
                }

                else if(dropdown === "0"){
                    alert("Do Step 1 first");

                }else if(dropdown >= "1") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'showData.php',
                        data: {
                            datumvon: datumvon,
                            datumbis: datumbis,
                            dropdown: dropdown
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            $('#inner').load('#inner');
                        }

                    });

                }else {
                    alert("Error");
                }
                return false;
```

The problem was some kind of syntax error in the javascript part. Thanks for the help